# Why it is showing error while installing mysqlclient?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.x

I am trying to install `mysqlclient` using `pip install mysqlclient` but it's showing the following error:

```
pip install mysqlclient
Collecting mysqlclient
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d0/97/7326248ac8d5049968bf4ec708a5d3d4806e412a42e74160d7f266a3e03a/mysqlclient-1.4.6.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: mysqlclient
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for mysqlclient ... error
  Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-haimRr/mysqlclient/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/tmpnpNImepip-wheel- --python-tag cp27:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/_exceptions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/compat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
  running build_ext
  building 'MySQLdb._mysql' extension
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python2.7-PPrPZj/python2.7-2.7.15=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -Dversion_info=(1,4,6,'final',0) -D__version__=1.4.6 -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c MySQLdb/_mysql.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/_mysql.o
  MySQLdb/_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_field_to_python’:
  MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1145:33: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘PyInt_FromString’ discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]
           return PyInt_FromString(rowitem, NULL, 10);
                                   ^~~~~~~
  In file included from /usr/include/python2.7/Python.h:89:0,
                   from MySQLdb/_mysql.c:38:
  /usr/include/python2.7/intobject.h:37:24: note: expected ‘char *’ but argument is of type ‘const char *’
   PyAPI_FUNC(PyObject *) PyInt_FromString(char*, char**, int);
                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python2.7-PPrPZj/python2.7-2.7.15=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python2.7-PPrPZj/python2.7-2.7.15=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/_mysql.o -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lmysqlclient -lpthread -lz -lm -lrt -latomic -lssl -lcrypto -ldl -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/_mysql.so
  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lssl
  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcrypto
  collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
  error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for mysqlclient
  Running setup.py clean for mysqlclient
Failed to build mysqlclient
Installing collected packages: mysqlclient
  Running setup.py install for mysqlclient ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-haimRr/mysqlclient/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-Z3t7oY-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix=:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/_exceptions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/compat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    running build_ext
    building 'MySQLdb._mysql' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python2.7-PPrPZj/python2.7-2.7.15=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -Dversion_info=(1,4,6,'final',0) -D__version__=1.4.6 -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c MySQLdb/_mysql.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/_mysql.o
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_field_to_python’:
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1145:33: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘PyInt_FromString’ discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]
             return PyInt_FromString(rowitem, NULL, 10);
                                     ^~~~~~~
    In file included from /usr/include/python2.7/Python.h:89:0,
                     from MySQLdb/_mysql.c:38:
    /usr/include/python2.7/intobject.h:37:24: note: expected ‘char *’ but argument is of type ‘const char *’
     PyAPI_FUNC(PyObject *) PyInt_FromString(char*, char**, int);
                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python2.7-PPrPZj/python2.7-2.7.15=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python2.7-PPrPZj/python2.7-2.7.15=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/_mysql.o -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lmysqlclient -lpthread -lz -lm -lrt -latomic -lssl -lcrypto -ldl -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/_mysql.so
    /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lssl
    /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcrypto
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-haimRr/mysqlclient/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-Z3t7oY-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix=" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-haimRr/mysqlclient/
```

How can I fix this error ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is saying that you miss `lssl` and `lcrypto`.

To solve you need to install `libssl-dev`.

Comment: How to install libssl-dev?